# How to remove unnecessary fonts from react-native-vector-icons?

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

My app bundle size is 19.7. I decided to remove unused icons of react-native vector icons.

So, I added following code in ***android/app/build.gradle***

```
 project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'SimpleLineIcons.ttf'] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

I placed it just **before**:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

Then I re-created the bundle. But the size is still 19.7 MB.

Also, I extracted the bundle and found that in asset folder there were react native vector icons which I don't use except 1 icon set.

Can I remove those files from bundle directly ?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @SagharMirali not yet !

Answer (score 1):

Well, changing **build.gradle** by above method did not work. So, I did my own research and found a solution.

I was using only **SimpleLineIcons** with Native Base. Native Base uses **Ionicons** by default (for checkbox, radio etc). That means I had to keep these 2 fonts.

So, I removed other fonts except these 2 from asset folder:

```
android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/
```

And then created the build. My bundle (.aab) size reduced from 19.7 MB to 18.1 MB.